# Javascript : skip calling the chaining methods based on a condtion dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions, method-chaining

I have an array of objects, I call a series of methods on the array. I wanted to skip in between methods based on a condition. Is there a generic way to handle it instead of having an if/else block?

When a filter is applied i wanted to call filter method in this array, when filter is not applied i want skip that.

```js
// when filter is applied
    salesActivityTypes
         .filter(s=>s.selected)
         .map(key => key.name);

//when filter not applied
    salesActivityTypes
         .map(key => key.name);
```

I don't want to use something like if/else block and copy-pasting the same code twice. Is there any better way to handle this?

The order of methods call matters and should'nt change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an if/else block, and if/else expression is enough and can be part of your chain:

```
(filteringActive
  ? salesActivityTypes.filter(s => s.selected)
  : salesActivityTypes
).map(key => key.name);
```

Alternatively, in this particular case you can also pass a no-op callback to `filter`:

```
salesActivityTypes
  .filter(filteringActive ? (s => s.selected) : (_ => true))
  .map(key => key.name);
```

Comment: Nice. Can the first variant be done when I have multiple conditional filter expressions? I'm not sure how to access the intermediate results in a chain... I currently only see the second variant being possible but it would call the expression on each element compared to the first one. Or I would need to use variables for results. Basically when I have `array.map(...).filter(...). (someflag ? filter(...) : pass) .map(...)`

Comment: @E.Körner Yeah, for that you should introduce a variable for the first part of the chain

Answer (score 1):

Just add another check inside the `.filter` callback for whether filtering is active.

```
salesActivityTypes
     .filter(s => filteringActive ? s.selected : true)
     .map(key => key.name);
```